# Jquery bind issue and update after bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following test code:

```js
$('.add').on("click", function(){
console.log('count items: '+$('.item').length);
  var newItem = '<div class"item">New Item</div>';
  $('.items').append(newItem);
})

$('.items').on('click', '.item', function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">
Add
</button>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

question 1: why is the count always 3 and how can I get the updated count
question 2: why the new items are not fading on click as the first 3 ?

thanks

Comment: `<div class"item">` <- this should look wrong to you :)

Comment: Thank you!  That did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The count is always 3 because there are 3 things with the class 'item' and `$('.item')` finds all three and when you add a new item you have a typo `<div class"item">`.

Comment: The event is actually correctly bound to it. This also fails due to the typo.

Comment: I didn't realize you could bind events like that. HA! Learn something new every day.

Comment: Very useful. [Here's the official article on it.](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)